# Java Socket Server - Client; Stuck on Server side

Tags: java, sockets

This is the first time I am not able to find the problem/bug in my code so now I am asking stackoverflow xD

I am currently learning how to write a simple Server - Client network to understand how Sockets and Server Sockets in Java work. Therefore, I wrote a "program" consisting of a Server, Client and Handler class. The Handler class is responsible for receiving the Client's messages and sending a response. Sending from Server to Client works perfectly fine, the Client receives the message. However, when the Client sends a message to the Server, it does not receive anything. The BufferedReader I am using is stuck on the `readLine()` request.

```
//This is the broken down version of what is happening in my Handler class
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port); //These two lines of code actually happen in the Server class
Socket client = server.accept();              //but to simplify it I put them here
//Setting up the IO
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
//The Handler is waiting for the Reader to be ready and then prints the input
//Additionally, it sends a confirmation to the client
while(true) {
    String input;
    if(in.ready()){
        if ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(input);
            out.println("Message Received");
            if(input=="close") break;
        }
    }
}

//Expected output: "Message Received"
//Actual ouput: none, it gets stuck at in.ready() or in.readLine()
```

When I send a message from the Client it should just print the message and send a confirmation to the client but instead it either never gets past the `if(in.ready()){...}` part or gets stuck at `if((input=in.readLine())!=null){...}` if I remove the first if-statement. I used IntelliJ to debug it and the InputStream doesn't contain any message or the carriage return which is expected by `readLine()`. I find that to be really weird as the sending and receiving part of both the Server as well as the Client class is (mostly) the same.

The only thing I could think of that would maybe be the cause of this problem is that the Client somehow has problems sending the message.

```
//This is the broken down version of what is happening in my Client class
Socket client = new Socket();
client.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost",port));
//Setting up the IO
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //I am using a Scanner for the message inputs
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
String input;
System.out.println("Enter the first Message: ");
while ((input = scanner.nextLine()) != null) {
    String inServer;
    System.out.println(input); //The input is correct
    out.println(input); //I am suspecting it has something to do with this line or the PrintWriter
    //This part works perfectly fine here while it does not in the Handler class
    if (in.ready()) {
        if ((inServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inServer);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Enter next Message: ");
}
Expected output: inServer
Actual output: inServer
```

As you can see, the general setup of this part is the same as in the Handler class, yet something seems to go wrong when sending to the Server. I don't know if it is the Server (I don't think so because the same code for receiving messages works just fine in the Client class) or the Client, where in that case it would have to be a problem with the PrintWriter or something like that.

I have already looked at other/ similar questions here on stackoverflow but didn't find anything that would solve my problem.
The full code for the classes if someone wants to replicate everything in detail: (Pastebin links)

[Server class](https://pastebin.com/kS2s7R4B)

[Client class](https://pastebin.com/36gPPhex)

[Handler class](https://pastebin.com/Cbsj5yKb)

Comment: Perhaps you could call out.flush() after you print?

Comment: I set autoFlush to true when I instantiated the PrintWriter so I already have that implemented

Comment: `in.ready()` isn't doing anything useful here, it's just wasting CPU time in a tight loop. Just move the code inside the `in.ready()` if statement to be outside that statement and delete the `if`.

Comment: Your code works for me. When the client sends a message, e.g "Hello World", the server prints the line `[Server] received Message: Hello World`

Comment: Did you make any changes to the code or did you just copy the classes from pastebin?

Comment: Well... I moved everything into a new project and it works just fine now! WTF was going on? Anyways, thanks for helping me solve this problem @PresidentJamesK.Polk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems the question has been answered...
It seems like it had something to do with the IntelliJ project the code was in. I had to move it into a new project and now it works.
The issue is resolved now and if someone wants to use this code as a base for a Server-Client system, I'll leave the pastebin-links working.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is that you use read() method of the classes that implement Reader (BufferedReader is one of them). The syntax would be like this :

```
String data = "";
int i;
while ((i = in.read()) != -1){
    data += (char)i;
}
```

This way is a lot more reliable and does not have the carriage return problem.